# floating point in python gives a wrong answer

Tags: python, python-3.x

I calculated the following:

```
>>> float(10.0-9.2)
0.800000000000000*7*
```

even doing 10.0-9.2 gave the above result. Why is the extra 7 coming in the result?

I'm on python 3.2.

Comment: why are you even converting the result of a float subtraction to a float? what would you expect it to be other then a float?

Comment: @duffymo: im new to python and never saw this coming. always better to ask rather than commit silly mistakes :)

Comment: Yeah, I agree.  No need to make people feel bad for asking a question about an implementation detail that's actually pretty arcane when you think about it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Floating point arithmetic has built-in problems as it's based on a binary approximation of  numbers.

There is [a good explanation of this](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/floatingpoint.html) in the Python docs.

You can check out [the `decimal` module](http://docs.python.org/library/decimal.html) if you need more exact answers.

Comment: Thanks.. was looking for this. Answers my question

Comment: You have greatly alleviated my pain.  I thought it was a bug at first, but it looked way too perfectly inaccurate to not be a mathematical mistake related to python type logic.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `round()`

for example:

```
print(round(10 - 9.2, 2))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is typical of binary floating-point arithmetic on all platforms.  If your application is not tolerant of rounding errors within this margin of error, you can use [Decimal](http://docs.python.org/library/decimal.html) objects instead.

Comment: Of course, `decimal` also implemented floating point numbers, just with a different base - meaning, you still get inaccuracies, just the ones people are used to.