# Why don't large floats in Python 3 get cast to integers properly?

Tags: python, floating-point, integer

I'm trying to cast a large float to an int in python. A simple example is: `int(1648083600123123000.0)`

Why does this get cast to `1648083600123122944` instead of `1648083600123123000` ?

Comment: While this question [floating point in python gives a wrong answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10403434/floating-point-in-python-gives-a-wrong-answer) is not a perfect duplicate, the root cause is the same and the accepted answer is likely your best solution.

Comment: The float that you're passing to `int` _already_ has value `1648083600123122944.0` (try for example printing `format(1648083600123123000.0, ".0f")`). The `int` conversion isn't changing the value at all - it's just changing the type.